# Using collections in ATL application

Tags: c++, collections, atl

How can I use std collections as vector and list in an ATL application? if it is not possible what can I do instead, aside from using the collections described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15e672bd.aspx ? I want for example to store some strings in a list as

std::list< CString > alist.

Answer (score 1):

You can quite happily use them, you just can't pass them across a COM boundary as COM doesn;t know what a stl collection is. You can pass them across an in-proc COM boundary using a pointer, but just be careful that you know what you're doing in such circumstances.

Comment: Passing across a DLL boundary can be dicey because the two DLLs must agree on which version of the runtime library they are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please, by all means do so. STL is way better designed than most ATL classes are (with regards to exception safety, genericity, etc).

Beware when storing `CCom[Qi]Ptr` in collections, your library may complain about the overloaded address-of operator. There is a wrapper somewhere in ATL.

Exposing the collection as a COM collection is much harder though.